# How to represent a 50 digit integer with an array of int?

Tags: java, arrays

The guidelines call for the following:

```
BigIntegers will be represented with 50 digit arrays of int (where each integer in the array is an integer in the range 0..9).

You will have a class called BigInteger that has the following methods:
BigInteger( ) --- initialize the BigInteger to 0
BigInteger(int n) --- initialize the BigInteger to the value of n
BigInteger( BigInteger n) --- a copy constructor
```

My question is, what is the most effective way of going about this? Currently, I have:

```
public class BigInteger {
    int[] BigInteger = new int[50];

    public BigInteger() {
        for(int i = 0; i < BigInteger.length; i++) {
            BigInteger[i] = 0;
        }
    }
```

Which seems to work, but only for initializing the array to 0.... I have checked around Stack Overflow, but am coming up empty. Could someone point me in the correct direction on how to go about this?

Comment: 1. it would probably be easier if your field was not also called BigInteger.
2. where exactly is the problem you are facing? what do you mean by "effective"? You will probably want to divide by 10 and take the module for consecutive array entries until your integer is 0 in the second constructor and just copy the array in the third?

Comment: Not seems to have a better, but for clearer code, better not reuse same name for Class and an attribute, you can misunderstand later if you read code you won't know quickly which one it is

Comment: You don't need to zero out the `int[]`. Numeric arrays are initialized to zero by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a java guy but what about that.

```
public BigInteger() {
    for(int i = 0; i < BigInteger.length; i++) {
        BigInteger[i] = 0;
    }
}

public BigInteger(BigInteger bigInteger) {
    for(int i = 0; i < BigInteger.length; i++) {
        BigInteger[i] = bigInteger[i];
    }
}

public BigInteger(int n) {
    String nstr = n.toString(); // not sure
    int pos = 49;
    for(int i = nstr.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        BigInteger[pos] = Integer.parse(nstr [i]); // parse each char, you get the idea
        pos--;
    }
}
```

Edited thanks to @Andreas.

Comment: Those are not the most efficient ways of doing it in Java. Besides, it appears to be an assignment for OP to complete, so let's try not to just give the answer away. Also, last method is wrong.

Comment: Should the last method just be the first method but using n? That sounds too easy, but I'm not sure how else to go about it

Comment: @Andreas well, he asked for help, I'm not here to judge if he deserve to find an answer or not. About my last method, can you edit or elaborate ? As I said, I'm not a java guy.

Comment: If `n` is 42, you get array of `[4, 2, 0, 0, ..., 0]` (48 zeroes). Now, is that 42, 420, 4200, ..., or 4.2e49? --- Oh, and first method has redundant code, since array is already all zeroes.

Comment: Indeed, thanks for pointing this out, I've edited my answer. That could be way better but that is the best I can do from my phone.